# Material-UI React component library: ternary operator doesn`t work inside media query

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change a flex container height inside media query. Container (root) height defines according ternary operator well. Ternary operator inside media query for container height doesn`t work. It takes only first value (480px).

Here is a relevant snip:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: ({ isModelsVisible, modelsCount }) => ({
    height: !isModelsVisible ? '480px' : `${(modelsCount / 3) * 210 + 250}px`,
    minHeight: '480px',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    transition: 'height 1s ease',
    '& button': {
      zIndex: 10,
      color: theme.palette.textColor,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.backgroundColor,
      borderColor: theme.palette.textColor,
      margin: 50,
      '&:hover': {
        color: theme.palette.textColor,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.backgroundColor
      }
    },
    '@media (max-width: 480px)': {
        height: !isModelsVisible ? '480px' : `${(modelsCount / 2) * 210 + 250}px`
    }
})
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZnVx.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyOzX.png)

Comment: Hi, as far as I see, you are setting this outside of your component. So, `isModelsVisible` will be evaluated only once here, when loading your page.

Comment: Hi, Michael. If I understood you correctly, ```isModelsVisible``` defined inside component because if I click the button, in devtools we see how it`s value changes but only in root.

Comment: The value you see in devtools is not related. When you render your component, the `useStyles` has been already set, then its value is not updated on component re-rendering even if `isModelsVisible` changes.
Could you provide a more detailed example (within CodeSandbox for example) so I could take a look ?